# Whats the difference between a Signer and Accounts in Anchor? Where should they be used?

Tags: account, signer

```
pub fn startstuffoff(ctx: Context<StartStuffOff>) -> Result<()> {

        let base_account = &mut ctx.accounts.base_account;

        base_account.total_gifs = 0;
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn add_gif(ctx: Context<AddGif>) -> Result<()> {

        let base_account = &mut ctx.accounts.base_account;
        base_account.total_gifs += 1;
        Ok(())
    }


>#[derive(Accounts)]<br>
pub struct StartStuffOff<'info> {<br>
    #[account(init, payer = user, space = 10000)]<br>
    pub base_account: Account<'info, BaseAccount>,<br>
    #[account(mut)]<br>
    pub user: Signer<'info>,<br>
    pub system_program: Program <'info, System>,<br>
}<br>

>#[derive(Accounts)]<br>
pub struct AddGif<'info>{<br>
    #[account(mut)]<br>
    pub base_account: Account<'info, BaseAccount>,<br>
}<br>

>#[account]<br>
pub struct BaseAccount{<br>
    pub total_gifs: u64,<br>
}<br>
```

I have followed the build space tutorial which is quite good. I'm just confused about the aspect where I need to use Signer, Account and base account and how it will be able to grant permission to our specific users to allow them to increment Gif counter in accounts.

### Questions

1. What's the difference between a Signer and Accounts?
2. Where and when should they be used?
3. What happens if I use one instead of the other?

Answer (score 5):

The `Signer` is the authority of that transaction i.e the wallet that would need to sign with its private key for that transaction.

For example in the `StartStuffOff` instruction, the `user` account is specified as the signer since it pays for creation of `base_account`. This means that verification of its private key would be required for the transaction to continue.

A wallet is required to sign for any transaction that debits it, a sensible constraint that ensures that only the actual owner of the wallet can authorize a transfer of funds from it.